# Where are the sources for 2 different ends for Al Hamichya?

Tags: blessing, mezonot-beracha

Sometimes the bracha of Al Hamichya ends with the words "v'al hakalkalah", [like it is shown here](https://www.tefillos.com/al_hamichya.asp).

Sometimes those two words are left out, [like shown here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=al%20hamichya%20text&sxsrf=ALeKk03lX8RwPQK3R-Ls_sdTR-Uj6_q1rg:1614805792966&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=TsbKp0jeZqmrFM%252CQyPSm1_1doC5zM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRAxEi0BDbIyQ1IpUrRRGvPhIU7Rg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwituq6thJXvAhX-EFkFHTgwASoQ9QF6BAgHEAE&biw=1264&bih=720#imgrc=1oUQub0UxnS8XM)

What are the reasons for this difference in these two, and are there sources for their differences?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.208.15.1?lang=bi&with=Talmud&lang2=en